# DAX: Count Distinct Values by Ref & location

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to count the distinct "locations" per "Shipment Ref".

I have the following formula which gives me the total count of locations by shipment ref but not the distinct count.

```
ShipLocationCount =
COUNTX (
    FILTER (
        CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365,
        EARLIER ( CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF] )
            = CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF]
    ),
    CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[DELIVERY_ADDRESS_CODE]
)
```

I want to then run a measure and use this calculated column as a filter to say where `ShipLocationCount > 1`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this instead of a filter?

```
ShipLocationCount =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[DELIVERY_ADDRESS_CODE] ),
    FILTER (
        CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365,
        CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF]
            = MAX ( CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF] )
    )
)
```

You could also try something like this:

```
ShipLocationCount =
COUNTROWS (
    SUMMARIZE (
        CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365,
        CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF],
        CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[DELIVERY_ADDRESS_CODE]
    )
)
```

The `SUMMARIZE` function groups distinct combinations of the columns referenced.

---

**Edit:** If you intend to use these formulas as a calculated column rather than as a measure, then they need to be modified to take into account the row context they live in.

```
ShipLocationCount =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[DELIVERY_ADDRESS_CODE] ),
        ALLEXCEPT(
            CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365,
            CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF]
        )
    )
```

And

```
ShipLocationCount =
COUNTROWS (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365,
            CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF]
              = EARLIER( CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[SHIPMENT_REF] )
        ),
        CustomerProfitabilityReport_Full_D365[DELIVERY_ADDRESS_CODE]
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Alexis , I have tried both solutions that you have provided. I have taken both expressions and input them into calculated columns. The first solution, `Distinctcount`, gives me a value of **1** for every record? The second expression, `Summarise`, gives a value of **4337** for every record? My aim is to count the distinct number of delivery address codes per shipment ref. For example, there could be 100 products/lines under 1 shipment reference. 50 with one delivery location and 50 with another, so next to every record, the distinct count would = 2 for that shipment reference.

Comment: @leTurner Right. That's because I wrote them as measures instead of calculated columns. The evaluation context is different for a calculated column.

Comment: Both of those work! Thanks! Is there a difference between the two or are they just different ways to get the same result?

Comment: They are different ways of achieving the same end goal. I'd recommend the first one as it's more obvious what it's doing.

Comment: Perfect thanks! And is there a way of telling weather something should be a measure or calculated column? Or if someone gives me a solution in the future, how to recognise it as either or?

Comment: It's not always obvious which it is and sometimes the same formula work either way, but if it references a slicer or filter setting then it's probably a measure and if it has raw column references without an aggregate function it's probably a calculated column. In general, you just pay attention to if it makes sense within its evaluation context.